# キショキショ mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation, sentence

[image]

In the first sentence the character says being in the same class as someone you feel at ease with, is fun.

But then he adds

こいつは昔からそういう感性なくてキショキショだけど

The sentence sounds odd to me. "But this guy ever since a long time ago had no awareness of that so it's pretty gross?"

And his answer is...

"別になくない" Not particularly?

Answer (score 2):

キショキショ(だ) seems to come from 気色(が)悪い through its slangy variation キショい. 感性 is "sensibility", and in this context the word particularly refers to that of feeling it fun to be in the same class as their friends. One character describes his friend as キショキショ "creepy" because of the lack of such a common sensibility, and the friend protests that（その感性が）なくないよ, which can be seen as double negation of ある.

Comment: I took "なくないよ" as.. "Not particularly" so an actual positive  "I have it"?

Comment: 別に in response is sometimes almost meaningless, so I think its translation can be simply "I have it." but if you want make your translation reflect 別に well, it is also possible to say "I'm not particularly lacking in it." or similar. (Sorry for indirect answer, but I'm not good enough at English to grasp the nuance of just saying "not particulary" here...)